# Failed to set MokListXRT: Out of resources when booting Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: secure-boot

I just installed ubuntu 21.04 on a brand new msi b650M mortar wifi motherboard, and I am getting two messages before the system boots:

**Failed to set MokListXRT: Out of resources**

**Could not create MokListXRT: Out of resources**

After that the boot process goes on succesfully, but it's scaring to have those messages there.
I already set SecureBoot inside the BIOS menu and also enabled it from MockUtil.
This message doesn't show up when booting from the usb stick live cd.

How can I get rid of those messages?
Thanks in advance.
PS: my motherboard model is MSI B560M Mortar Wifi

Comment: Update UEFI. You may just disable Secure Boot and the messages won't appear.

Comment: Thanks @ChanganAuto , may I ask you how can I update UEFI? Sorry for my inexperience in this area...

Comment: I see that the error was just fixed a few days ago:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/shim/+bug/1924605

I just activated the "development"/"proposed" updates and that updated my shimx64, and those message disappeared.